# Release APK error Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, release

I generated the unsigned release APK in Android Studio and it does not work. I run my app in debug on my phone and it works perfectly, but the release apk does not.

The app just haves to show simple text in textviews and it does not ... I do not know what to do.

Please help

Comment: Can you please provide more information ? Does it install but gives error while running or is it not getting install at all ? Pls check if you have enabled to install APK from unreliable source.

Comment: Thanks, but i found the solution

Comment: I learned recently - never assume an unsigned APK will behave just like a signed APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign it.  All apks, including debug ones, must be signed to be used.  The debug ones just use an automatically generated keystore for signing.

Answer (score 0):

After entering Generate Signed APk and just changed the buildTypes in the section of Gradle i changed minifyEnabled true to false.

That was all.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled proguard (i.e  minifyEnabled true) and specifically getting "Wrong number of Segments" error (this is related to JWT based API call authentication) in release build then add these rules in your proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes InnerClasses

-keep class io.jsonwebtoken.** { *; }
-keepnames class io.jsonwebtoken.* { *; }
-keepnames interface io.jsonwebtoken.* { *; }

-keep class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
```